Transition strip from carpet to laminate hardwood floor
I had laminate hardwood floor installed in my dining room and hallway but the guy that installed the floor didn't put any transition strips down and there's about 5 inches from carpet to laminate and he cut the laminate so I can't add  to it to close the space how can I transition it

5 inches isn't a transition strip situation. Please revise to explain better or post a clear photo.


Don't pay until he fixes it.

Add a complementary/contrasting material (oak, marble, tile) to bridge the gap. You don't specify where this gap is located so I am assuming it is between rooms.


